# Difference between a race and a dead lock

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing

In concurrent programming, what are the differences and the common points (if any) between a **race** and a **dead lock** ? An detailed answer would be appreciated ;).

Comment: take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130079/difference-between-racearound-condition-and-deadlock). it's vivid.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at [Description of race conditions and deadlocks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317723)

> **Race Conditions**
>
> A race condition occurs when two
>   threads access a shared variable at
>   the same time. The first thread reads
>   the variable, and the second thread
>   reads the same value from the
>   variable. Then the first thread and
>   second thread perform their operations
>   on the value, and they race to see
>   which thread can write the value last
>   to the shared variable. The value of
>   the thread that writes its value last
>   is preserved, because the thread is
>   writing over the value that the
>   previous thread wrote.
>
> **Deadlocks**
>
> A deadlock occurs when two threads
>   each lock a different variable at the
>   same time and then try to lock the
>   variable that the other thread already
>   locked. As a result, each thread stops
>   executing and waits for the other
>   thread to release the variable.
>   Because each thread is holding the
>   variable that the other thread wants,
>   nothing occurs, and the threads remain
>   deadlocked.