# What exactly is a deadlock and race-conditions (C++)?

Tags: c++, deadlock, race-condition

I got an interview for a developer internship position, and they're making me write a test tomorrow (got the interview offer today, so it's kind of a short notice). Bear with me and my n00bish questions, but I haven't done C++ in around 4 months and I had to study for two midterms, so I don't have a large amount of time to look this up myself.

Essentially, I'm wondering what deadlock and race-conditions are in C++ are, and what are some simple and intermediate-level examples of this.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a race condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition)

Comment: google will give better results for this. you might get ready answers than waiting here for detailed answers.

Comment: These terms are not going to be more meaningfully applied to C++ than to any other language that supports some kind of concurrency.  The generic definitions can be applied directly to C++.

Comment: This is more of a general question than a c++ question.  Deadlocks and race conditions occur with threads throughout computing.

Comment: Try this question, as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130079/difference-between-racearound-condition-and-deadlock

As phrased here, this isn't really an ideal question for the stack overflow format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html) have a good anecdote that explains deadlocks:

*"Deadlock describes a situation where two or more threads are blocked forever, waiting for each other. Here's an example. Alphonse and Gaston are friends, and great believers in courtesy. A strict rule of courtesy is that when you bow to a friend, you must remain bowed until your friend has a chance to return the bow. Unfortunately, this rule does not account for the possibility that two friends might bow to each other at the same time."*

And this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition) addresses race conditions.

Comment: I think this is a very bad explanation of deadlock, and as the interviewer I would ask for another example. Now I might be wrong, but I still would ask for another example and if you don't have one, then you don't know what a deadlock is.

Answer (score 1):

If you're more specific on which platform, then we can give more explicit examples. e.g. if it's Windows, then a making your process multi-threaded (e.g. `CreateThread`) and create scenarios whereby each thread are competing for resources that might block (`CreateEvent` & `WaitForSingleObject`) also `SendMessage`.